# How to call a function on click of a checkbox which is a popup on click of d3 element like rect

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js

I am having a rectangle which is d3 element, I want to click on that rect and a popup should come which will be having checkbox. On click of that checkbox a function should be called. 
As of now when I call a function in the html, that particular function is not invoked

```
mini.append("g").selectAll("miniItems")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rect")
            .attr("x", 200)
            .attr("y", function(d,i) {return y2(i*1.2)+5;})
            .attr("width", windowWidth - 700)
            .attr("height", 15)
            .attr("stroke", "grey")
            .on("click", onClick);/*on click of d3 element this function is invoked*/

  function onClick(d){
     let content;
    content = "<div style='background: white;width:70px; box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #797878;height:30px; padding:8%'><input type='checkbox' id='myCheck' (click)='onClaim(d.executionId)'></input>"+ "claim" + "</div>";
     div.html(content)
       .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
        .style("display", "block");
   }

 function onClaim(value){/*this function is not executed*/
        console.log(value);
}
```

[image]

I am not getting any solution in order to invoke that function 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add events the `d3` way as you already are using `d3`?

Within the `onClick` function, you can bind a `click` event to the input#myCheck.

```
div.select('input#myCheck').on('click', function () {
    if(this.checked) // checking if the checkbox is checked
        onClaim(d.executionId);
});
```

And please post a working snippet which makes it easier to answer (as your post was missing definitions of `div`, `mini` etc. Anyway, I created a snippet using sample code here:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg#chart');
var div = d3.select('div.tooltip');

var data = [{id: 1, executionId: 1}, {id: 2, executionId: 2}];

svg.append("g").selectAll("miniItems")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rect")
            .attr("x", 100)
            .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (i*100);})
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 15)
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .on("click", onClick);/*on click of d3 element this function is invoked*/

  function onClick(d){
     let content;
    content = "<div style='background: white;width:70px; box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #797878;height:30px; padding:8%'><input type='checkbox' id='myCheck'/>"+ "claim" + "</div>";
     div.html(content)
       .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
        .style("display", "block");
     div.select('input#myCheck').on('click', function () {
      if(this.checked)
       onClaim(d.executionId);
     })
   }

 function onClaim(value){/*this function is not executed*/
        console.log(value);
}
```

```css
div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg id="chart" width="400" height="400"></svg>

<div class="tooltip">

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Shashank thanks a lot for your reply :) It works now. Only thing is that "this.checked" is having some issue (in IDE it is underlined with red), this does not affect the output, but ng build fails due to this. I think this issue is because I am using typeScript. The message displayed on hovering on the "this.checked" is "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'BaseType'.
  Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Element". Any alternative way to check whether the checkbox is checked rather than using the above approach

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm not sure how typescript casts but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535018/property-checked-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement) and think it might help: `const input = this as HTMLInputElement; if(input.checked) { onClaim(d.executionId); }` . It's basically getting the input element and checking it's `checked` property so I'm sure you can figure out how to get an HTML element's property in typescript.

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues with quotes in your code. Try this:

```
 content = "<div style='background: white;width:70px; box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #797878;height:30px;'>
       <input type='checkbox' onClick='onClaim(d.data);'>
     </div>"
```

You were closing the surrounding " at the end of 30px;.
I replaced that with a single quote and added a double quote at the very end.

Comment: hi @sean Leroy, thanks for your reply :)  but actually there was some mistake while posting the question with the quotes... So now I edited it and still its not working... Can you please point out where I have made mistake

Comment: Is there an error in your console or is it simply not executing with no indication why?

Comment: when I hover on that particular function onClaim , i get "'onClaim' is declared but its value is never read' " i get this message. So that means that particular function is not called at first place. I am not getting how to call it so that it can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Hlo dkshaaa,

you can try this.

Since you are using checkbox instead of onClick you can use onChange.

So instead of this

`<input type='checkbox' id='myCheck' (click)='onClaim(d.executionId)'>`

you can use

`<input type="checkbox"  id="isCheckBox" (change)="onClaim($event, d.executionId)"/>`

and in angular component you can use the event as

```
function onClaim(event, execId) {
    if(event.target.checked){
       //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

hope this helps. ;-)

Comment: Hi DP, thanks for the reply but as I said that onClaim function is not invoked at all. When i hover on that  function it is shown as ''onClaim' is declared but its value is never read' "...

Comment: @DeekshaMulgaonkar I think you have to create dynamic component for that pop-up. I'm not sure if any easier solution is there.